# SmartGit Hg "Authentication Failed"

Tags: git, bitbucket, smartgit

I am using SmartGit Hg for a couple of months. I am using Bitbucket repo. I created another bitbucket account then cloned the current repository to the SmartGit. When I tried to commit and pushed (ofcourse it will ask for password), it says "Authentication Failed". Please help...Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you push to BitBucket from command line?

Comment: No, I haven't tried..

Comment: I switched to "use system SSH client" in preferences and it worked for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perhaps SmartGit remembers wrong account credentials to authenticate you on BitBucket.
Goto **Edit menu -> Preferences -> Authentication**
and remove credentials for the repository that fails.
Then next time you push SmartGit will ask you for both login and password.

Comment: I am not getting the dialog box to enter the credentials again

Comment: and I dont have this repo there

Comment: For some reason, this is not working. Updating, removing then readding credentials will not work for me. My solution is below.

Comment: @Jeremy The solution provided by you below works perfectly.

Comment: its not remembering wrong credential, reenter it again will result in same result

Answer (score 27):

This works for me.
Go to **Edit>Preferences>Hosting Providers**. On your Hosting Providers(I use Bitbucket for example) **select** it, click **delete** and click **add**. **Select hosting**, click **Generate API Token** automatically opens browser and generates token then **copy** go back to your smartgit then **paste** the token and finally click **add**

Comment: Thanks ! It worked for me. Github + Smartgit 20.2.4 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Also, remove credentials from Edit>Preferences>Authentication. It works for me

Comment: this is working, no user/password request again

Comment: SmartGit still asks for a password :(

Comment: Check that your token has not expired, thanks man, it worked for me.

Comment: Did not work for me. it has before, but no more. After token had been copied to smartgit, I get a list of repos. I select the one I want, click OK. After a few seconds, the output window says  "Add Remote Repository: Authentication using OAuth failed; check your GitHub Hosting Provider configuration in the Preferences."

Answer (score 20):

None of the answers given ended up resolving my issue on SmartGit.

I went in Edit ->Preferences -> Authentication but the list of known credentials was empty so was the list of Hosting Providers.

The reason was that SmartGit was storing my credential in Windows Credential Manager.

To resolve the issue, I went to Control Panel -> Credential Manager -> windows Credentials, select the specific credential you wish to update and choose to edit it and then update your credentials

[image: Change your credentials in Windows Credential Manager]

Comment: For completion's sake: I removed the credentials and then SmartGit used the API key I had stored in preferences/hosting providers.

Comment: I had one git credential stored in the Windows Credential Manager. To avoid the 'repository not found' error I had to delete this credential. Then, the next time I try to push smartgit simply pops up the GitHub username/password interface.  But then, I immediately get an email saying that GitHub has added a new personal access token.  Not super clear what's going on here, so a bit more documentation would be helpful.

Comment: This is the only solution that helped me in the end, I tried all the others first, then I tried this and it did the job immediately. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An easier approach to re-installing, but you will need to set it up again.

Delete: `c:\Users\{YOUR_USER_NAME}\AppData\Roaming\syntevo`

Once you re-launch SmartGit, it may noticed an issue with the credential helper. If so, then force it to use SmartGit by adding this to your `.gitconfig`

```
[credential]
  helper=
```

That file is located: `c:\Users\{YOUR_USER_NAME}\.gitconfig`

Re-launch SmartGit, do a PULL and it will prompt you to set a Master Password. Once complete, it will then ask you for the project credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error while authenticating with Git over HTTPS, after much frustration I uninstalled SmartGit and deleted everything in my SmartGit AppData folder.

(on Windows Delete **c:\Users\{YOUR_USER_NAME}\AppData\Roaming\syntevo\SmartGit**)

Once I reinstalled, all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `myaccount@` at the beginning of the repository URL was missing.

After selecting and opening the repository on the left pane, I had to click on the **Remote** menu, then **Properties...**.

In the field **URL or path**, I had something like `https://github.com/org/repo.git`, and I modified it to `https://myaccount@github.com/org/repo.git`. It asked my password and... bingo.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution works only if you disable restriction on github

in Github, in the **organisation** : go to : Third-party => oAuth application => click on disable restriction

Answer (score -1):

I used these SmartGit troubleshoot recommendations:
http://www.syntevo.com/doc/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6979745

Specifically, I simply redid pull / fetch of each origin from the GIT-Shell tool. It worked, and then SmartGit started to accept credentials just OK.

Previous on these thread recommendations did not work for me, and I did not want to reinstall SmartGit.

In Git-Shell:

```
1  git pull origin1 branch
2  git pull origin2 branch
```

Answer (score -1):

Un My case it was cause miss-configuration with SSH client.

`SmartGit > Preferences > Authentication`

Changed: "Use Smartgit as SSH Client" to "Use system SSH Client"