# Smartgit continues 403 error

Tags: bitbucket, smartgit

In windows, I've got a problem with Smartgit.
After setting up everything and cloning a new repository, it seemed to work and I could pull, push and commit everything on that repository.

The next day, I couldn't anymore and I'm constantly getting a 403 error:

> Remote: Too many invalid password attempts. Try logging in through
>   the website with your password.

Now we are using Bitbucket and with our other developers and everything seems to works out great. However, for me it doesn't seem to work. The funny thing is, that it does work (perfectly) when I use sourcetree.

I already tried everything that was suggested on another question regarding the same problem ([SmartGit Hg "Authentication Failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020645/smartgit-hg-authentication-failed)) but I still can't get any results.

The thing I find very strange though is that, under `Edit > Commands > Authentication` there is no "Known credentials repository".

Comment: Do you have Bitbucket **Hosting Provider** configured in the **Preferences**? In this case, SmartGit will use the OAuth "refresh" token to request an "access" token for repository access. I'd try to re-setup the Bitbucket Hosting Provider.

Comment: I've done this like a million times but I still get the error.
I have the idea that for some reason, SmartGit remembers the wrong credentials.
But, this is the 'funny' part, in "Known credentials" there is literally nothing.

Comment: You may try to start over with a fresh settings directory (see About dialog)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: On your Windows machine, go to Credential Manager, tab Windows Credentials , remove all git / bitbucket releted credentials, try again. You will be asked to authorize via Browser (Atlassian), make sure you use correct login credentials, and that should fix it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).